# Jquery inputmask time not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I have been using jquery input mask plugin to mask a input as HH:MM:SS format. but time is not working. Other mask working fine. why?

here is my code

```
var selector = $("#time");
 $(selector).inputmask("hh:mm:ss", {
  placeholder: "HH:MM:SS", 
  insertMode: false, 
  showMaskOnHover: false,
  alias: "datetime",
  hourFormat: 12
 }
);
```

I changed hh:mm:ss as 99:99:99 that time it's working but not validating hour and minutes.

Comment: Please ask your question with proper information to find solution.

Comment: What information do you want to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need change `$(selector)` to `selector`
you can try with this js lib

```
 <input id="time" name="test1"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
$("#time").inputmask("hh:mm:ss", {
  placeholder: "HH:MM:SS", 
  insertMode: false, 
  showMaskOnHover: false,
  alias: "datetime",
  hourFormat: 12
 }
);
</script>
```

Comment: No. Masking is working but I cant type anything in the input. and I cant remove HH:mm:ss placeholder too.

Comment: Could you tell me what "inputmask" pls are you using ?

Comment: Is there any option to make the mask with milliseconds? Something like this hh:mm:ss:zzz